# string comparison in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

how do we compare strings in makefile?

in makefile

```
MAKECMDGOALS ?= debug
DBGDIR = build/debug
RLSDIR = build/release

ifeq  ($(MAKECMDGOALS),"debug")
    O = $(DBGDIR)
else
    O = $(RLSDIR)
endif
```

I tried following comparisons:

```
($(MAKECMDGOALS),"debug")
($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug)
($(MAKECMDGOALS),'debug')
($(MAKECMDGOALS), ' debug')
```

also

```
ifeq "$(strip $(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))" "debug"
```

but everytime it enter else block and does release build.
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Remove the quotes (and the spaces). Make considers them as part of the string.

Comment: Quotes are not special to make.  It treats them just like any other character.  There is an annoying (I would remove it if I could) form `ifeq "foo" "bar"` where quotes are not ignored, but everyone should just pretend that form doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you should not have any quotation marks. The following works for me:

```
$ cat Makefile
MAKECMDGOALS ?= debug
DBGDIR = build/debug
RLSDIR = build/release

ifeq  ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug)
    O = $(DBGDIR)
else
    O = $(RLSDIR)
endif

all:
%:
        @echo $(O)

$ make
build/debug

$ make foo
build/release
```

But I would advise against checking it this way, as `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` may have more than one target and the test will fail:

```
$ make debug
build/debug
$ make debug foo
build/release
build/release
```

If you still wish to check this variable, it would be better to check if an interesting target shows among others, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
MAKECMDGOALS ?= debug
DBGDIR = build/debug
RLSDIR = build/release

ifeq ($(findstring debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),debug)
    O = $(DBGDIR)
else
    O = $(RLSDIR)
endif

all:
%:
        @echo $(O)

$ make debug
build/debug

$ make debug foo
build/debug
build/debug
```

Comment: You should use `$(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` rather than `$(findstring...)`.   `$(findstring debug,blah_debug.o)` would give you a false positive

Comment: Also, I personally prefer using `ifneq ($filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)` as opposed to using `ifeq`, if for nothing else to prevent repeating the `debug` literal...